# How many times do I need to install unison?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, filesystems, unison

If I need to synch 2 server with unison do I need to install unison on both server or only one in enough?

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

thank you in advance!

cheers

daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it on both client and server. Straight from their manual: [http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prelim](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prelim)

> Next, we'll get Unison set up to synchronize replicas on two different machines.
>
> Follow the instructions in the Installation section to download or build an executable version of Unison on the server machine, and install it somewhere on your search path. (It doesn't matter whether you install the textual or graphical version, since the copy of Unison on the server doesn't need to display any user interface at all.)
>
> **It is important that the version of Unison installed on the server machine is the same as the version of Unison on the client machine.** But some flexibility on the version of Unison at the client side can be achieved by using the -addversionno option; see the Preferences section.

Answer (score 1):

To sync between two (or more) machines, you need to install it on both (or all).